# Nodejs Async upsert issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am currently working on a Nodejs project that uses MongoDB and closely monitoring the data flow of the Nodejs server.

The code of my Node server goes as following:

**Receive.js**
1. Node server receives a JSON text file
2. Node server tells MongoDB (upsert) we received a file

**Process.js**
3. Node server upserts JSON file to MongoDB
4. Node server tells MongoDB we processed said file.

The problem is that sometimes **#4** occurs before **#2** despite **#1** always occurring before **#3**. My monitor program starts displaying that there are more files processed than received. Is there a way to fix this problem without making this server completely synchronous?

For example if I send my Node server 500 JSON text files, the very last time Node executes **#2** should be prior to the last time **#4** gets executed.

**** Note: `App.js` calls .receive from `Receive.js` and `Receive.js` calls .save from `Process.js` ****

**app.js**

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  mongodb.createConnection(function(db){
    if(db){
      console.log('success connecting to mongodb!');
    }
  });
});  
app.post('/log', logCollection.receive);
```

--
**Receive.js**

```
exports.receive = function(req, res, next){
  var usagelog = req.body.log;

  if(!usagelog){
    log4js.logger.error("Usagelog is Null!");
    res.end("fail");
  }else{      
    count++;

    //Upsert the Receive Count for Monitor  
      mongodb.getConnection(function(db){

          dateFormat.initDate();
          //Upsert trip (usage logs)
          var currentDateTime =  moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
          db.collection("ReceiveCount").update( {"date":dateFormat.currentDate(), "pid":process.pid }, 
                    {"date":dateFormat.currentDate(), "IPAddress": ip.address(), "pid":process.pid, "countReceive" : count, "LastReceivedTime": currentDateTime}, 
                    {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {            
            });
          });

    //End Receive count
    var usagelogJSON = convertToJson(usagelog);
    var usagelogWithCurrentDate = addUpdateTime(usagelogJSON);
    usagelogDao.save(usagelogWithCurrentDate, res);
  }
};
```

--

**Process.js**

```
exports.save = function(usagelog, res){
  var selector = upsertCondition(usagelog);

  mongodb.getConnection(function(db){
    //Upsert trip (usage logs)
    db.collection(collectionName()).update(selector, usagelog, {upsert:true, fullResult:true}, function(err, result) {
      if(err){
        log4js.logger.error(err);
        res.end("fail");
      }else{

        if(result.nModified == 0)
            countInsert++;
        else
            countUpdate++;

        //Upsert Processed Count (both Updated and Inserted     
        db.collection("ReceiveCount").find({"date":dateFormat.currentDate(), "pid":process.pid },{}).toArray(function (err, docs) {

            var receivecount = docs[0].countReceive;
            var receivetime = docs[0].LastReceivedTime;
            var currentDateTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
            var MongoCount=0;

            db.collection("raw_"+dateFormat.currentDate()).count(function(err, count){
                console.log("raw_"+dateFormat.currentDate());

                MongoCount = count;
                console.log("Mongo count is :" +MongoCount);
            });

            db.collection("ReceiveCount").update( {"date":dateFormat.currentDate(), "pid":process.pid }, 
                {"date":dateFormat.currentDate(), "IPAddress": ip.address(), "pid":process.pid, "countUpdate" : countUpdate, "countInsert":countInsert, "countTotal":countUpdate+countInsert, "LastProcessTime": currentDateTime,
                "countReceive":receivecount, "LastReceivedTime":receivetime, "MongoCount":MongoCount}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {      
            }); 
        });
        res.end("success");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Despite the upvotes here there is not a very clear question in SO terms. There are ways to handle this with async processing and libraries that help as well. But we need to see some code for this to be a question that can be answered and solved. Show your code so we can see where you are going wrong. Upvotes != answers.

Comment: Better for updating, but I think the context of how you are calling your exports of "receive" and "save" that is the more important part of your problem right here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async module (https://github.com/caolan/async). Here is the pseudo code:

```
async.parallel([
  fun1(cb) {
    tellDBYouReceivedFile(..., onFinished() {
      cb();
    });
  },
  fun2(cb) {
    saveYourFileToDB(..., onFinished() {
      cb();
    });
  },
], function() {
  tellDBYouProcessedFile();
});
```

What you are trying to achieve can't be done completely asynchronously because the last step (#4) has to wait for #2 and #3 to be finished first. The above example can make #2 and #3 asynchronous, and guarantee #4 is executed last.